# Splitting a branched river network at point layer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, line, splitting

I need to split a country-scale river network (polyine) at certain barriers (point) so the length of (branched) river sections that have a certain minimum length. I used the following procedure:

1) Merge/Unsplit river network to one long line (only one row in the attribute table).

2) Split line at Point.

The problem is now that it **not only splits the lines at the barriers, but also at intersections/branchings** within the river network. I also tried Xtool's split line feature with similar results, and gvSIG's sextante toolbox didn't work at all for me. Any suggestions?

I am using ArcGIS 10 SP5, but also open to solutions in Qgis or gvSig

Comment: I did not find a solution for this problem yet, but I managed to a build a complicated and slow tool in the model builder... It's not really fit to release to the public but if anyone else has a similar problem and finds no way to solve it feel free to contact me.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to split a line layer with a points layer using QGIS. Do you think your tool could be adapted to do this?

Comment: Sorry it is built in the ArcGIS model builder. But to be honest it is a _really_ ugly solution... Since we kinda changed some of the goals of our project, I did not need it any more and never bother to make a "polished" version of it. If you manage to put something together in qgis/python I would be highly interested though :)